# Checkbox not set in ASP.NET MVC 3

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, checkbox

I'm trying to initialize my checkbox in controller like the code below, but in the view it's not selected whether it's true or false

controller :

```
 foreach (var item in AssignedUsers)
 {
     if (dc.App_UserTasks.Any(u => u.UserId == item.UserId && u.TaskId == ProjectTask.Id))
        {
            Users.Single(u => u.Id == item.Id).IsChecked = true;
        }
     else
        {
             Users.Single(u => u.Id == item.Id).IsChecked = false;
        }
  }
```

view:

```
 @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Responsibles.Count; i++)
    {
         @Html.CheckBoxFor(u => u.Responsibles[i].IsChecked)            
    }
```

send model from controller to view :

```
 var EPT = new EditProjectTaskModel
            {
                ProjectId = ProjectTask.ProjectId,
                Title = ProjectTask.Title,
                ProjectName = ProjectTask.App_Project.ProjectName,
                Id = ProjectTask.Id,
                Description = ProjectTask.Description,
                EstimatedTime = ProjectTask.EstimatedTime,
                Status = ProjectTask.Status,
                Responsibles = Users.ToList()
            };
            return PartialView("_EditProjectTask", EPT);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your User ViewModel looks like this

```
public class UserViewModel 
{
  public string Name { set;get;}
  public int UserId { set;get;}
  public bool IsSelected { set;get;}
}
```

And you have your main view model has a collection of this UserViewModel

```
public class EditProjectTaskModel 
{
  public List<UserViewModel > Responsibles { set; get; }

  public EditProjectTaskModel()
  {
    if(this.Responsibles ==null)
       this.Responsibles =new List<UserViewModel >();
  }
}
```

Create an editor template called `Responsibles.cshtml` with the below content

```
@model YourNameSpace.UserViewModel 
@Html.CheckBoxFor(x => x.IsSelected)
@Html.LabelFor(x => x.IsSelected, Model.Name)
@Html.HiddenFor(x => x.UserId)
```

Now include that in your main view like this, instead of the loop

```
@model EditProjectTaskModel
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
  //other elements
 @Html.EditorFor(m=>m.Responsibles)
 <input type="submit" value="Save" />
}
```

If you want to get the selected checkboxes on a form submit.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Save(EditProjectTaskModel model)
{
  List<int> userIDs=new List<int>();
   foreach (UserViewModel user in model.Responsibles)
   {
     if (user.IsSelected)
     {
       //you can get the selected user id's here
       userIDs.Add(user.UserId);    
     }
   } 
}
```

Comment: `foreach (UserViewModel user in model.Responsibles)`

Comment: @3nigma : Thanks 3nigma. Fixed that.